# Django case insensitive "distinct" query

Tags: python, django, orm

I am using this django query

```
people.exclude(twitter_handle=None).distinct('twitter_handle').values_list('twitter_handle', flat=True)
```

My distinct query is returning two objects 
For example :

```
['Abc','abc']
```

How can i get case insensitive results ? like in this case only

```
['abc']
```

using django 1.9.6,
python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) along with [`Func() expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to apply `.distinct()` on lowercased `twitter_handle` value:

```
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Lower
>>> people.order_by().exclude(twitter_handle=None).annotate(handle_lower=Lower("twitter_handle")).distinct("handle_lower")
```

You can't append `values_list('twitter_handle', flat=True)` to the above query because you can't apply `distinct` on a field that doesn't exist in the `values_list` so you have to do it by yourself:

```
 >>> queryset = people.order_by().exclude(twitter_handle=None).annotate(handle_lower=Lower("twitter_handle")).distinct("handle_lower")
 >>> [p.twitter_handle for p in queryset]
```

or you can get lowercased `twitter_handle` values:

```
>>> people.order_by().exclude(twitter_handle=None).annotate(handle_lower=Lower("twitter_handle")).distinct("handle_lower").values_list("handle_lower", flat=True)
```

Comment: @Ozagur Vatansever , Actually i am dealing with a very huge data set, wouldn't annotate adds extra step in query ?

Comment: Yes, it might add some overhead to execution time because you apply distinct on a non-indexed field. You can define an index for `LOWER(twitter_handle)` field to overcome that. If you are using PostgreSQL here is how you can do it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: @Ozagur Vatansever , Yes i am using PostgreSQL thanks i will surely try that

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `annotate` to create a new field with the lower case value, then use `distinct` on that.

Try something like

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

(people.exclude(twitter_handle=None)
      .annotate(handle_lower=Lower('twitter_handle'))
      .distinct('handle_lower'))
```